# alamofire call on ios 13 failed

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

upgraded phone to iOS 13.1.1 and now getting the following error:

> responseSerializationFailed(reason:
>   Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error:
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around
>   character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around
>   character 0.}))

I'm using alamoFire 4.5

I tried to use responseString but that did not work

```
 afManager.request(Constants.APISyncUserEndpoint, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(queue: DispatchQueue.global()) { (response) in
```

On the iOS 13 emulator it works fine, but on the real device, multiple devices it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configurated your info.plist to accept arbitrary loads?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
```

You can read more details [here](https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-app-transport-security-exception-domains)